# Our developer profile, the administrator of the app, has been disabled by Facebook. How do we recover our app?

Tags: facebook

We've tried emailing disabled@facebook.com and that email is no longer active. It doesn't work.

Is there a way we can contact Facebook to help us recover our app? The Appcenter page is still active but we cannot enter the developers dashboard.

Help!

Comment: If it was a real user account that got disabled just go through the flow to recover the account. If it was a fake account file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and tell them which real user account you want to get added as an admin

Comment: It was a fake one, so I will try that second option. Get you posted on if it worked. thanks.

Comment: Do you have other admins on this app, if so you could try our appeal page: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Comment: Hey guys! Problem solved. I followed WizKid's suggestion and we got back the control of our app. Thanks for the comments!